# Azure AD OAuth token wrong audience (client credentials flow)

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get a OAuth token (client_credentials flow) to be able to call my API. I cannot get the proper audience in the token.

In Azure AD, I created 2 App Registration. One to represent my API, the other one to represent my Client.

In my API App Registration, I exposes an API
[image: App Registration - Expose an API]

As you can see in the screenshot I also added my Client App Registration as an "Authorized client applications".

I also added an App Role.
[image: App Role]

In my Client App Registration, I created a secret to authenticate.

I also added my API App Registration in the "API Permissions" and also Granted Admin Consent.

[image: API Permission]

My problem is when I am trying to get a token from Azure AD. I do the following in Postman :
[image]

But the token I get does not contain the audience I specified. It contains the default "Graph API" Audience.
[image]

I've been reading on OAuth for the past 2 days but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Also, please note that I cannot use the v2.0 endpoint because in the end, I do all this to be able to authenticate to my API in Power Automate and I don't have the option to use the v2.0 endpoint (and the resource or scope parameters).

[image]

Here's the token decoded

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your token and provide screenshots.

Comment: Good point Carl... just added it

Comment: Are you using the identity management authentication provided by the `Auth0 organization`?

Comment: I have tested this many times, and I think you are not using the OAuth 2.0 standardized authorization protocol.

Comment: In the OAuth 2.0 standardized authorization protocol, if you use the v1.0 endpoint, you should use the `resource` parameter instead of the `audience` parameter, it will not recognize the parameter. Only Auth0 organization will support this parameter.

Comment: I totally understand that but I don't have the option to use the "resource" parameter in Power Automate... as you can see in my screenshot, I need to provide the "audience". And it doesn't seem that I have the flexibility to choose between v1 and v2 in the options

Comment: Have you tried the Auth0 I provided in the answer?

Comment: Yes... Even with that if I set an audience I always get the Azure Graph API audience

Comment: Note that the request URL of Auth0 and OAuth 2.0 is different, it is `https://YOUR_DOMAIN/oauth/token` instead of `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/oauth2/token`.

Comment: In addition, as I said in the answer, only Auth0 accepts the `audience` parameter, and OAuth 2.0 does not recognize the `audience` parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In summary, I will post it as an answer.

Like I said in the comments, if you are using the OAuth 2.0 protocol, when you use the `v1.0` [endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to request an access token, you should use the `resource` parameter instead of the `audience` parameter, because the `audience` parameter is not recognized by the OAuth 2.0 protocol. Even if you do not selected this parameter in postman, you should be able to obtain a default ms graph api token.

The `audience` parameter is commonly used in Auth0 organization, but it has some differences from the OAuth 2.0 protocol. The request URL of [Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/call-your-api-using-the-client-credentials-flow#example-post-to-token-url) is as follows:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://YOUR_DOMAIN/oauth/token' \
  --header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data grant_type=client_credentials \
  --data client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID \
  --data client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET \
  --data audience=YOUR_API_IDENTIFIER
```

Comment: If the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I guess then my problem is that Power Automate only supports OAuth0 Thanks